# Merge the data in gridview

Tags: html, asp.net, sql, c#-4.0, gridview

In Gridview records as follows;

```
Date                   Session


6-jun                     1

6-jun                     2

6-jun                     3

6-jun                     4
```

from the above datagridview records i want as follows

```
 Date          Session

                 1

                 2 
  6-jun  
                 3

                 4
```

for that how can i merge the date in gridview make it into single column.

for that how can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Quick internet search and I find:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34337/How-to-merge-cells-with-equal-values-in-a-GridView

I downloaded and it works like a charm.
Here is a working example: http://techlearningblog.com/exp/mergecells/